# How to replace a part of variable column names from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas

In this sample dataframe which contains 3 variables:

```
data = {'A':['m', 'f', 'm', 'm'], 
        'B':['y', 'y', 'n', 'n'],
        'C':['ab','bc','cd','ef'] }


# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df  

    A   B   C
0   m   y   ab
1   f   y   bc
2   m   n   cd
3   m   n   ef
```

After some manipulations, the above dataframe becomes:

```
data1 = {'x0_m':[1,0,1,1], 
         'x0_f':[0,1,0,0], 
         'x1_y':[1,1,0,0],
         'x1_n':[0,0,1,1],
         'x2_ab':[1,0,0,0],
         'x2_bc':[0,1,0,0],
         'x2_cd':[0,0,1,0],
         'x2_ef':[0,0,0,1]}

# Create DataFrame 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 
df1

    x0_m    x0_f    x1_y    x1_n    x2_ab   x2_bc   x2_cd   x2_ef
0   1        0       1      0        1        0       0       0
1   0        1       1      0        0        1       0       0
2   1        0       0      1        0        0       1       0
3   1        0       0      1        0        0       0       1
```

I want to replace the `"x0"` variables with the column names in the original dataframe. For example, `"x0_m"` and `"x0_f"` should become `"A_m"`, `"A_f"` respectively.

I have identified two steps for this procedure:

**Step 1:** create a dictionary which will include variables x's and the corresponding column names. I tried this:

```
list_num = ['x%s' % (i) for i in range(3)]
list_num
['x0', 'x1', 'x2']
```

Extracting the column names from the original dataframe `df`:

```
features = list(df.columns)
features
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Then i tried to create a dictionary:

```
dict = {x: features for x in list_num}
dict
{'x0': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'x1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'x2': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
```

But, that is not what I want. I'm expecting:

```
{'x0': 'A', 'x1': 'B', 'x2': 'C'}
```

How to get the desired output.

**STEP2:** Replace a part of the columns in `df1` with the help of the dictionary created above.
This part, I'm completely lost. Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step2:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {'x0_m':[1,0,1,1], 
         'x0_f':[0,1,0,0], 
         'x1_y':[1,1,0,0],
         'x1_n':[0,0,1,1],
         'x2_ab':[1,0,0,0],
         'x2_bc':[0,1,0,0],
         'x2_cd':[0,0,1,0],
         'x2_ef':[0,0,0,1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 

colnames = list(df1.columns)
new_names = {'x0': 'A', 'x1': 'B', 'x2': 'C'}

for key, value in new_names.items():
    colnames = [col.replace(key, value) for col in colnames]

df1.columns = colnames

df1

    A_m A_f B_y B_n C_ab    C_bc    C_cd    C_ef
0   1   0   1   0   1       0       0       0
1   0   1   1   0   0       1       0       0
2   1   0   0   1   0       0       1       0
3   1   0   0   1   0       0       0       1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `str.replace()`:

```
df1.columns = (
    df1.columns
    .str.replace('x0', 'A')
    .str.replace('x1', 'B')
    .str.replace('x2', 'C')
              )
```

or using a dictionary:

```
for k, v in dct.items():
    df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace(k, v)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use list comprehension instead of the for loop? Something like `df1.columns = [...]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a dictionary comprehension together with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
mapping = {col: feature for col, feature in zip(list_num, features)}
>>> mapping
{'x0': 'A', 'x1': 'B', 'x2': 'C'}
```

To modify the columns in your second dataframe:

```
new_cols = []
for col in df1:
    a, b = col.split('_')
    new_cols.append('_'.join([mapping.get(a, a), b]))
df1.columns = new_cols
>>> new_cols
['A_m', 'A_f', 'B_y', 'B_n', 'C_ab', 'C_bc', 'C_cd', 'C_ef']
```

Comment: there is an additional "]" in new_cols.append() code line

Comment: Typo. I changed it from `mapping['a']` to `mapping.get('a', 'a')` to make the code more robust.  If it doesn't find `a` in `mapping` for whatever reason, it will just use the original prefix `a`.